# Dynamic minimum height for body?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a centred fixed width content `div`, and if there isnt enough content (ie, an small error page) the height of it is smaller than the height of my web-browser.

This leaves the footer in the middle of the screen, the and the background of the content div not continued to the bottom. Just looking like shit.

**Is there a way to force the content div to always fill the screen, if it's contents are smaller than the current screen?**

I realize this might have to use javascript, but I'm not very acquainted with it.

edit: If the user re-sizes the window, I'll want it to update as-well.

edit: It looks like I can use the `window.innerWidth`, `window.innerHeight` properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a sticky footer, not a resize of the body.

Check out Ryan Fait's great tutorial on how to do this: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Here's a demo of it in action: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: This will push the footer to the bottom, but will not extend the background of my main content div to the bottom

Comment: @caesay: You'll have to put the background in an absolutely positioned outer `div` or put the background in the `body` if applicable. Hard to say with no markup to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ryan Fait's [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).  It sounds like what you need, and is implemented in CSS.  I've used a variation for several projects and it Just Works.

Comment: You were beaten to it, and there's no reason to have two identical answers ;)

Answer (score -2):

Use can use this,

```
<style> 
        html,body{
            height:100%;
            margin:0;
        }
        #wrapper {
            min-height:80%;
        }
</style>
<div id='wrapper'>
hello
</div>
<div id='footer'>
    my footer
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I misinterpreted your question completely.
Now, edited the answer, see if it helps you now.